# why does my statement prints "loading" twice?

Tags: jquery

$("div").append("LOGO");

$('div').append("Loading");

> When I append them, I have logo in the div.class and loading in div#maine. If I remove the whole logo statement, the loading only prints once but having two statements prints loading twice. Can somebody please explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are appending LOGO and Loading in `div` directly, Which means every `div`

You should be doing

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('<div id="maine2">').appendTo('body').html("LOGO");
    $('<div id="maine">').appendTo('body').html("Loading");
});
```

The selectors should be unique for you to achieve the objective.

Comment: I have a question by doing that do you automatically create a class named class?

Comment: $(document.createElement('div')).attr('id', 'maine') even if I do your way by creating empty div with id maine, it displays nothing..

Comment: oh no sorry for the confusion. I am trying to create an new div with id maine and then append some text.